# Validação de sexo com input radio está dando erro?

Tags: javascript

Criei dois campos `input` `radio` para sexo e coloquei `value="m"` e no outro `value="f"`. Deixei como padrão o `input` com o `value="m"` `checked` (para que ao iniciar esteja checado), porém quando envio para o JS, mesmo se eu marcar o `input` `value="f"`, ele me retorna `"m"` por culpa do `checked`

O `input checked` está atrapalhando, mas não quero tirá-lo.

Esse é meu código de verificação dos `input radio` "sexo". Cada `input` tem uma `class()` com o mesmo nome. Dei um

```
querySelectorAll();
```

e joguei na variável `sexo`. A ideia é: se o primeiro `input (((sexo[0])))` estiver checado, então ele é `m`, caso contrário ele é `f`.

```
if(sexo[0].checked){
    sexo1 = "m"
}else{
    sexo1 = "f";
}
```

Comment: AKU você tem várias perguntas em aberto seria interessante você interagir e creditar (claro que com sua vontade) as respostas, fica um mão única o legal é quando se torna gratificante para os dois lados. Repense um pouco.

Comment: Tem como elaborar um [mcve]?

Comment: Não sei nem validar um input radio de sexo ainda mais responder autras pessoas! 

Não significa q eu não concorde, porem ainda nao tenho conhecimento necessário para ajudar outras pessoas

Comment: AKU claro, mas, estou dizendo as perguntas em aberto, quando são respondidas, você tem como testar porque geralmente é colocado um exemplo. É nesse aspecto eu entendo também a sua busca por conhecimento e precisando estamos ai ...

Comment: O @VirgilioNovic está a dizer que você não aceitou nenhuma das suas respostas nas perguntas que já fez para trás. É importante aceitar uma resposta quando resolve o seu problema, pois ajuda outras pessoas no futuro que passem pelo mesmo problema a seguir primeiro a resposta aceite, pois é a que o autor indica que resolveu o problema. Ao fazer isso também lhe dá um bonus de reputação a si e a quem respondeu, assim como motiva quem deu a resposta a responder no futuro pois vê que os seus esforços foram uteis.

Comment: @Isac é isso mesmo nesses aspecto de cooperação.

Answer (score 1):

Aqui vai um exemplo funcional que criei, pode se basear e modificar seu código.

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  console.log($('input[type=radio]:checked').val());  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="sexo" value="M" checked>M</input>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="sexo" value="F" >F</input>
<br>
<button>Checar Valor</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`inputs` do tipo `radio` da mesma coleção devem ter o mesmo `name` para que você possa escolher um ou outro:

```
<input class="sexo" name="sexo" type="radio" value="m" checked="checked" /> masculino
<br />
<input class="sexo" name="sexo" type="radio" value="f" /> feminino
```

Não há problema algum em deixar o primeiro marcado com `checked`, pois o JavaScript irá detectar normalmente qual está marcado:

```js
function checa(){
   var sexo = document.querySelectorAll('.sexo');
   
   if(sexo[0].checked){
      sexo1 = "m";
   }else{
      sexo1 = "f";
   }
   alert(sexo1);
}
```

```html
<input class="sexo" name="sexo" type="radio" value="m" checked="checked" /> masculino
<br />
<input class="sexo" name="sexo" type="radio" value="f" /> feminino
<br />
<br />
<input type="button" value="Verificar sexo" onclick="checa()" />
```

Comment: Vale lembrar que dessa forma está limitando o usuário a utilizar apenas dois inputs. caso o ' 0 ' não esteja marcado você deduz que o outro está , acho que existe uma falha no algorítimo.

Comment: @MateusVeloso Sim, foi o informado na pergunta, apenas dois inputs. A não ser que queira incluir um terceiro sexo rs

Comment: @MateusVeloso Sua resposta é boa, mas a pergunta não tem a tag jquery.

Comment: Por isso comuniquei que era apenas para se basear, ai caso ele não utilize ...